# Can you change the Gravatar associated with your email without a WordPress account?

Tags: wordpress.com, gravatar

I would like to change the Gravatar associated with one email address of mine (which shows up in [Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) next to my commits).

When I go to gravatar.com to do that, I'm [faced with this](https://en.gravatar.com/site/signup):

[image]

Do I **really** need a WordPress.com account? Or is there some workaround? Obviously I don't *want* to create an account just to change the frigging picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, before, you would have had to sign up with a Gravatar account. There's really no difference. They've simply unified their user credentials.

So, yes, you need to create a WordPress.com account. Don't worry, that doesn't mean that you'll have a WordPress blog. You can just use it for your Gravatar.

Comment: Fair enough. I sort of remembered that earlier you didn't need to register at all. Anyway, a slight annoyance but it didn't take long.

Comment: If you didn't have to register at all, then someone else could pick your photo for you....